# Remove Repeating and Control Characters in sed

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, text-editor

Let's say I have a word **at the beginning of a line**, HHEELLLLOO for example. How can I replace repeat characters with single characters. The output should be HELLO.

Also does anyone know how to remove or specify control characters in sed, ^H for example.

Comment: There is no portable way to specify control characters indirectly in sed. However, you can do so with Perl using hex, octal, or properties, which is the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "limiting repetition" from this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

An actual script, as inspired by `chown` and that site:

```
sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]\)\1\+/\1/g'
```

However, you won't be able to get `HELLO`, you would only get `HELO`.  A regex is not sophisticated enough to determine that there should be 2 L's.  For that, you would need to match the word to a dictionary.  Though, you could use the regex for that ... `H+E+L+O+` . . .

For the control characters, `\0xx` will match arbitrary ASCII characters.  You'll have to look up what `^H` represents.

Comment: That doesn't work: `echo banana | sed -e 's/\141//g'` says `sed: 1: "s/\141//g": RE error: invalid backreference number`.  Whereas `echo banana | perl -pe 's/\141//g'` says `bnn` just as you would expect.

Comment: Fine, I'll actually place the script in here . . . :)

Comment: @tchrist how about this: `echo banana | sed -e 's/'"$(printf '\141')"'//g' `

Comment: If you get rid of the `+` in your regex, it actually will do what the OP wanted. At least, according to the OP's example. In other words, it will take every pair of identical characters and remove one, so HHEELLLLOO becomes HELLO.

Comment: @Kevin, no one noticed that, apparently. And that's why I posted another answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### Question 1

Yes, regex can handle that. In sed:

```
$ echo HHEELLLLOO | sed 's/\(.\)\1/\1/g'
HELLO
```

This will do it.

#### Question 2

It may vary depending on your system. Here (BSD) you can type ctrl-v ctrl-h to
insert a literal backspace character to be interpreted by sed. Give it a try.

```
$ cat file
H^HE^HL^HL^HO^H
$ sed 's/^H//g' file > new_file
$ cat new_file
HELLO
```

Comment: I'm assuming they are, looking at the example given. Also, duplicated characters and backspaces means @seljuq70 is working with output from groff or something like. These things were used to make bold fonds, underline and etc in very old printers, but still in use. Less understands it this way. Try `echo H^HHE^HEL^H_L^H_O | less`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for removing duplicates: `sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]\)\1\+/\1/g'` but it will produce 'HELO' not 'HELLO'.  See the other Answer for the reasons why this is.

Comment: You have magic turned up to 11?  I think you have some escapes missing.  's/\\([a-zA-Z\\)\1\+/\1/g'

Comment: @islandcow it looks like that regex is missing the last `]` after the `Z`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo BookKeeper | perl -pe 's/(.)\1+/$1/gi'
Bokeper

$ perl -le 'print "\cSome \cEvil \cControl \cMess\c?"' | perl -ple 's/\pC//g'
ome vil ontrol ess
```

Technically, control characters are `\p{Cc}`.